# How to manager Cronjobs via web gui? I need only a library

Tags: linux, cron, web

For my web app I need to be able to run some Cron jobs and edit them and their frequency via web interface. **I already have a web app** and I want to embed this functionality in it.  I don't want a discrete one more app

I need only a library  to communicate with Cron. I haven't found any de-facto, standard and popular one or ones. Do they exist at all?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your platform and envirionment (Linux or Android, Apache or Nginx, PHP, Python or Perl, etc. ...) possible answers can be only based on guessing or opinions.

Comment: @U880D - you're unable to read the tags?

Comment: Unfortunately the tags do not specify the web service which is used, frameworks or languages. Would it possible to provide some more background information?

Comment: @Kargari: -1 to your question due your seemingly hostile/arrogant attitude in your comments to those who attempted to comment or reply to you. People here are to help you for free, so please be professional and friendly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the audience and the point of view, for one the de-facto standard could be [Webmin to Manage Cron Jobs](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Scheduled_Cron_Jobs). You may find the library there or at least some ideas within the source code.

There are also [discussions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832511/setting-up-a-cron-job-with-webmin) available.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use cron for this generally. You use a task processor like celery. Here's an example

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: I asked about a library for cron!